# My WiFi does not work in Sony Ericsson

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, cyanogenmod, sony-ericsson-xperia-x8

My Sony Ericsson X8's wifi has stopped working about a few weeks after rooting and installing the GingerDX v030.

Even though it is turned on and scanning, it does not connect to any WiFi.

I have tried rebooting, and also resetting the WiFi antenna (i.e., either by turning it off then on, or by switching to airplane mode and then back out of it).

I have to use the stock kernel otherwise the phone hard bricks.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I have managed to solve the problem by looking at some XDA forums.

Basically summarized here: -

1. Go into the WiFi settings.
2. Long press a remembered WiFi.
3. Select Forget All Networks. You might need to do it a few times.
4. Press the leftmost button (the one with literally four squares) to bring up a bottom menu.
5. Touch Scan.
6. Voila! WiFi working again!

The only drawback is that you need to grab passwords for each one of them again. :-(

Answer (score -3):

1. Take a backup
2. Reboot in CWM Recovery
3. Format cache
4. Format data
5. Format system
6. Wipe Dalvik cache
7. Reflash ROM

In that development site, they must have mentioned extra files to flash. Do that too.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Q&A site. Your answer is not a good fit as there's lots of unexplained things - What development site? What extra files to flash, do what too? An answer like that is not exactly like that would only get downvoted or lots of comments explaining/seeking clarification. Kind of like asking a monkey which direction is north, understand how poor it comes across. Might be worthwhile to edit your answer as much as you can to include a lot more information for the reader :)